# Different column names on different phones

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have just found out that on a phone made by HTC there is no such column in URI content://sms like 'delivery_status'
And therefore I have read that Android does not guarantee that these columns will be on every phone at all.

If I want to be able to support different phones what could I do?

What method can Android guarantee me in order to get what I want?

How can my application get data that it needs so it would be working on all phones?
(Every phone has a field 'delivery_status' it just may be in other place or named different)

Literature:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Comment: Well, it depends from what you want. Obviously the delivery_status column is not a guaranteed column.

Comment: I want to make sure that on every or just most phones users will install my app the app itself will be able to get info that it needs. And that's it. I need from phone sms address, body, date, protocol, seen, delivery_status

Comment: This strongly depends from the Manifacturer. For example HTC - they have this Sense whatever, which has an application for everything (this is also valid for Samsung with their touch wiz). The only thing which can be guaranteed can be found on the Nexus devices (unrooted) and/or the newer "stock ROMed" devices, which come with a clean stock version of the Android. You can't be compatible with all the devices on the planet, tomorrow there's going to be a company which will sell the most EPIC devices and they will have their own ROM too. Then your application will have to be rewritten.